# How to validate int value should not be nullable or string type?

Tags: validation, asp.net-web-api

My project uses validation block, and i am passing some complex data type from client side to server side model.
But sever side model accepts the null value as well as string values for the int data type property at server side, it sets the default value of constructor 1, how should i fix this issue?

```
 public int Sequence { get; set; }
```

and I am passing   `"Sequence": "",` from client side but this accepts it without error and sets the default value to 1 that is of constructor.
Or what annotation i should apply on it, i never used validation block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to enforce constraints is to add them to the Route template in your controller.  Example...

```
[Route("api/foo/{sequence:int}")]
public string Get(int sequence)
{
    return "value";
}
```